# Apache will not start with httpd-ssl.conf

Tags: apache-2.2

Trying to set up SSL on this machine, I would appreciate some help here.

Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
static ip  98.189.118.100 (example)

SSL certificates are from SSLS.com

Ports 80 and 443 are open

In the httpd file I have the following uncommented.

ServerRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2"

Listen 80

ServerAdmin admin@cox.net

ServerName  98.189.118.100

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

#include httpd-ssl.conf

the following are uncommented in httpd-ssl.conf

listen 443

VirtualHost *default*:443

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

ServerName  98.189.118.100

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/ 98.189.118.100.crt"

SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/ 98.189.118.100.ca-bundle"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/privkey.txt"

When I uncomment #include httpd-ssl.conf Apache will not start

Comment: Apache 2.2 in ancient and your questions about it will get closed.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: and by the way: does not work is not an acceptable error description from an Business Administrator. please read carefully [ask] and update the question by editing  ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. I need to run 2.2 because I have some legacy software which will not run on 2.4.. Error logs dont show anything on windows 7. I think I said it would not start.

Comment: What error you observed after enabling include httpd-ssl.conf  file ?

Comment: I did not see an error in the error log. I would just get a message that apache would not start. In any case, I can not get the ssl certificate to apply properly. Chrome complains that although the certificate is valid, it is using an outdated security configuration.

Answer (score -1):

simple? solution, comment this line

#SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"

and apache starts. Not sure why.